# Instructions for creating Google Data Studio Connector outdated?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm attempting to build a connector for Google Data Studio. Whilst following the instructions on https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started I'm getting stuck at creating the manifest file. The option **view -> Show manifest file** is no longer present in the [script editor](https://script.google.com/). Also the steps for publishing the script seems to have changed. Instead of **Publish > Manage Deployments** there is now a multitude of options like Deploy as Web app, Deploy as API executable, etc. in this menu. None of these options generates a Publishing ID that GDS accepts.

Who can help me out to get started?

Comment: You must hit the button "Request Developer Access". Then add all data and  after a few days the option Show Manifest appears in the menu.
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started

Comment: Are you able to get started with the connector development now?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot see the "Show manifest file", it means you do not have developer access to the Community Connectors. [Request for Community Connector developer access here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSes5CdFbIJAvK-FAdDmsRfICJ5Mz-m_cSg_u-PvqsU8q0jYfg/viewform).

Once you are given the access, you should get a confirmation email. After that, you can view the **view -> Show manifest file** option in Script editor.

The deployment menu item has changed. Instead of going **Publish > Manage Deployments**, you have to do **Publish > Deploy from manifest**. Our documents will be updated to reflect this. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.